# Linear programming sensitivity analysis

Tags: linear-programming

As I am begineer I want to know if we add new constraint  to a lpp then what will change is this
*Feasible region or feasible solution
*Optimal solution
*Both

Answer (score 0):

Consider a linear program in standard form: $$\qquad \quad min \space c^Tx\\s.t. \qquad Ax = b\quad\\ \qquad x\geq 0$$

When you add a constraint, you are adding a row to the matrices $A$ and $b$. 
 
In geometric terms, the feasible set either reduces or remains the same. 
 $\ $ 1. $\ $ If the feasible set remains the same, the optimal solution is not changed. 
 $\ $ 2. $\ $ If the feasible set is reduced, the optimal solution could either remain unchanged or increase.